# Custom SQL Database - To rebuild from scratch or Fix what we have got

Tags: indexing, duplicates, relational-database, naming-conventions, normalization

We have a database that drives a lot .Net Applications, Reports and a fair bit of data manipulation that occurs on a daily basis. This database has slowly evolved over many years by many different developers and as a result it is in quite a state. The main issues are:

- Naming Conventions are inconsistent
- Lots of inefficient indexes
- Many tables require normalizing
- Table relationships are virtually non-existent across many tables
- Duplicated Data
- Many un-used tables, SP's Agent Jobs etc...

Pretty much a DBA nightmare!

So I am looking at what the best options are for addressing this. We will be looking to do this in the background so there is no disruption to normal operations so I have decided one of two approaches.

1. Develop a new database from scratch and slowly cross over functionality to the new database.
2. Work at identifying the exact areas of concern in the current database and fixing them in a structured pragmatic way.

I firstly wanted to check if there was a best practice approach for this kind of project (either of my two suggestions above) and it would be interesting to know what the pro's and con's are for each method.

Any other additional info on this kind of project would be greatly appreciated if anyone has experiences going through this kind of thing!

Comment: I recommend option 2. The effort to fix an existing database is much the same as building and migrating to a new one, except you execute the project in smaller, more manageable pieces and get results much faster. Big design upfront multiplies the risk of missing details, breaking changes, and the project getting derailed.

Comment: Many thanks for your response reaanb - appreciate the feedback! We have decided to go with a 'hybrid' approach if that makes sense. It will be a new database that is built up as requirements specify, but we will be going through the original database in detail along with other locally developed apps & reports to ensure we get everything we need. Implementation will also be staged through the process of the development.

Comment: This way we feel confident that we will only be left with what we need. We have so much unrecognized/redundant/non existent  data, tables, SPs, Indexes, Fk Relationships etc... that it would take a life-time to simply identify ALL individual issues.